# Create variable with 2 groups and defining an interval for a group

Tags: r, variables, grouping, intervals

I would like to create a grouping variable.

```
If Candy.df$winpercent > 55354046, winner high
if Candy.df$winpercent >= 43078911 & <= 55354046, winner low
```

This is what I implemented so far:

```
Candy.df$result2 <- ifelse(Candy.df$winpercent > 55354046 , "winner_high", ifelse >= 43078911 & < 55354046, "winner_low")
```

My problem is to correctly enter a code for the interval

Comment: See the `cut` function.

Comment: @ SteveM please can you show me the solution in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really try to do it yourself first.  But here's an example:

```
x <- sample(1:10, 20, replace = TRUE)
mybreaks <- c(0, 3, 6, 10)
mylabels <- c('no win', 'low win', 'high win')
winstatus <- cut(x, breaks = mybreaks, labels = mylabels)
```

Just plug in your values for x, mybreaks and mylabels.

Comment: thank you I got the result. Lidl.df$result2 <-  cut(Lidl.df$winpercent, breaks = c(43078911, 55354046, 81866257) , labels = c("winner_low", "winner_high"))